# How can I fix sorting issue in Odoo?

Tags: odoo

I am using below code to sort. Everything works fine till E999. E1000 goes into hiding somewhere and is not part of sorting.

_order= 'employee_code desc'

Comment: whats the code for first employee? is it E1 or E001?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. It is E001

Answer (score 0):

Records are sorted based on string comparison. It compares first characters and if these are equal, second character is compared and so on.

In your case comparison works only to E999, because the next code has one character more than all previous codes.

When comparing E1000 with E999, the first code is smaller, because the second character of the first code is smaller.

The order of codes will be like this:
`E098, E099, E100, E1000, E101, E102`

In smaller scale you can see the same situation here:

```py
x = ['E01', 'E02', 'E22', 'E99', 'E100', 'E10', 'E11']
x.sort()
print(x)
```

Output:

```py
['E01', 'E02', 'E10', 'E100', 'E11', 'E22', 'E99']
```

So, to solve this issue you just need to increase the length of code (by adding 0 before the number if it is to short), so it always has the same length for all codes.